# Event examples?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I do not understand fully when Events should be used and therefore I believe there is a big gap in my toolkit.  I started with a company three years ago and not a single .NET declares a single event.

I have read plenty of literature on the subject e.g. here: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/381790-why-use-events and here [When to use events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151786/when-to-use-events) and I am able to use them.  However, I don't understand when I should use them.

I realise events follow the Observer pattern and the Observer pattern helps with loosely coupled code.  I am looking for a commercial example of an event.  I am looking for explanations rather than code.

I notice that the following Observer example does not use events: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx.

Comment: This question should be closed as "too broad". However, the general answer to your question is: whenever some class has something to say, and some other class wants to hear it, but the first class doesn't know ahead of time about the second class.

Answer (score 4):

A good example of when events are useful is if you have a user control that is hosted inside of an .aspx page.

Let's pretend that I have a user control that displays the details of a person. The user control has the fields relevant to a person, such as name, age, gender, etc. This user control could be hosted in several pages (i.e. Page1.aspx, Page2.aspx, etc.). At the bottom of the user control is a save button, when that button is clicked, I want a message displayed at the top of my .aspx page that says something along the lines of "Person successfully updated.".

Without events, the user control would need to know which page was hosting it so it could tell the page that it needs to update the text of a label to display at the top of the page. This works fine if you just want to use the user control with this one page, this is called tight coupling. Now what if I want to use the user control on another .aspx page; uh oh the "Person successfully updated" message is hard-wired to the "old" page and does not work.

Enter events. Within the user control I can define an event that can be raised by the user control at the appropriate time, in this example's case when the save button is clicked.

Meanwhile back in the .aspx page, it needs a way to say I want to be informed of events raised by the user control, so it subscribes to the user control's event via the reference it has to the user control itself. Now when the event is raised by the user control, the page reacts and does whatever it needs. Any page that uses this user control can choose to subscribe or ignore the events raised by the user control and can perform different logic based upon the event being raised. For instance, another page could display a message and also log the successful update of the information.

In short, events provide a conduit for information to pass through from one component (user control) to another (page) without both sides needing to know of each other's existence. This allows for the user control to be independent of the .aspx page, but still be able to provide information to it, if it (the page) chooses to care about that information.

Comment: Thanks. Is it fair to say that events are used in the presentation layer rather than the business layer or data layer?

Comment: @w0051977 - it is fair to say that you will see events in the presentation layer a lot more than you will see them in other layers, but that does not mean they have no use in other layers of the application. For instance, your business layer might have an event raised when a message arrives from a service layer. I would recommend using them in the presentation layer until you feel more comfortable with events and then venture out to the other layers for potential usage.

Comment: Do you use events in all your apps? +1 by the way.

Comment: @w0051977 - I cannot think of an application that I have worked on that did not use events, but maybe very early on with .NET 1.0, that was over 10 years ago so forgive me if I cannot recall. :-)

Comment: Thanks.  So you have declared events in all your apps? I don't mean the framework events like button.click.

Comment: Yep, like I said user controls are a common place for events.